# Why is implementing a generic interface so counter intuitive?

Tags: java, generics, interface

```
interface Foo<T extends Number>{
}

class Bar<T extends Number> implements Foo<T>{

}
```

Why does the class have to be written that way instead of:

```
class Bar<T extends Number> implements Foo<T extends Number>{
}
```

Surely the second way is clearer.

Comment: Why do you think the second way is clearer?

Comment: How many languages do you know that have the `extends` and `implements` keywords? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's the same `T`, so it's redundant to say it `extends Number` again.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
class Bar<T extends Number> implements Foo<T> {
```

`T` is defined at the first occurrence and used at the second. `extends Number` constrains the type that `T` can be instantiated with. You can put such constraints only at the place where `T` is defined.

It is similar to ordinary function parameters, where you write the type only in the declaration and not at the places where you use the parameter.